# Access VBA - Open Form to Specific Record from Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report that lists Deposits, with the DepositID set as a hyperlink.  OnClick of DepositID, it opens the Deposit Entry form to that particular record.  However, the form opens to a new record instead of the one the user clicks on.  I think it is because I have another bit of code that runs OnLoad of the form that goes to a new record, and it might be executing that after executing the OnClick code.

OnClick of DepositID from the report:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DepositForm", acNormal, "", "[DepositID]= " & [DepositID]
```

OnLoad of the Form:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Is the OnLoad code running after the OnClick code, and effectively not showing the specified record from the report?  Not sure how to fix.

Comment: There's a quick and easy way to check via the power of print debugging! Have you tried putting a `Debug.Print "Here"` or a `MsgBox "Here"` in each of your event handlers? Give them different messages and you'll be able to see which ones trigger when and in exactly what order. If OnLoad is triggering after OnClick, you'll be able to see it.

Comment: Most definitely, the order for Form Open is `Open > Load > Resize > Activate > Current`.  You could remove the `Criteria` part of your OpenForm call and simply move the `DepositID` to the end of that statement (as a open args). Then simply check on `Open` for open args -if not present goto new record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be using the AddNewRecord in your OnLoad event.

If you're using the form for both edit/add purposes, you should have two command buttons that open the form - one for each purpose

Remove this line from Form_Load

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Use the edit command you have right now exactly as is - or add EditMode

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DepositForm", acNormal, "", "[DepositID]= " & [DepositID], acFormEdit
```

Add a new button to Add New Records as in:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DepositForm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution!