# On Click, Open Form to Matching Record

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am working in MS Access 2016. I have my dashboard form that contains a sub-form that shows jobs for the current week. I have "hyperlinked" the quote # field (not an actual hyperlink, just looks like one) that has an on click event tied to it. When a user clicks the quote number, I want the quote form to open up to that record.

I have tried various solutions, such as [Access VBA - Open Form to Specific Record from Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729591/access-vba-open-form-to-specific-record-from-report). However, when the form opens, only some of the data relevant to that record is shown. The main data remains blank and when I check for what primary key ID it filtered to, it is always "new".

The current code I adapted from the linked post is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Quote__Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "QuoteForm", , , "QuoteID = " & QuoteID, acFormEdit
End Sub
```

Why is this only partially working and loading the form to "new" as the record?

Answer (score 0):

You miss a value for quoteID. Perhaps you mean:

```vb
Private Sub Quote__Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "QuoteForm", , , "QuoteID = " & Me!QuoteID.Value, acFormEdit
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still did not seem to remedy it. It still opens to "new". What I find so weird, is that other fields on the form are opening correctly, but the main fields are not (quote #, job name etc)

Comment: Then either QuoteID doesn't hold the value you expect, or something else is going on.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere within the query that the sub-form is based off of. I will keep tinkering with it and see if I can find out what is happening.